# Server Validation with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Can You Please Tell me Any One, how to write server validation with angularjs, I referred So Many Sites, No One Can Explain Properly.

Is It Possible With Server Validations With Angularjs. Please Help me With a Proper Demo/Reference.

Because I want to Implement in my Current Project.

Comment: bdw angular is client side framework..how could client side will do validation on server side..

Comment: [This has a few examples](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_validation.asp) Look at ng-dirty it gives you your own set of properties to build your server side validation and set custom validation messages

Comment: AngularJS is a pure frontend framework. So you can't do server-side validation with it, since it doesn't execute on the server. Check the documentation of your server-side framework to know how to do validation on the server.

Comment: you can use `$http` to communicate to server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a server side API. Any server side validation would live in the PUT and POST methods of your API.

Then with Angular you use the Angular [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) or [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) service to access your API.